# What is the best way to handle train set having one more row than test set?

Tags: cross-validation, prediction, data-imputation

I have train and test data sets of the [Ames, Iowa housing prices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) data set.
The source data has been split approximately 50/50.
My train set has 1460 observations and the test set has 1459.

I've found that when predicting on the test set, R complains when the train and test sets do not have the same number of observations.

I am a beginner, so I'm unsure whether to impute one row in the test set or to delete, perhaps, a random row from the train set.

**So should I delete a random row from the train set or impute one row in the test set?**

Or is there a better solution altogether that I don't know of?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.  

In fact, I posted this question because I had been getting a warning "'newdata' had 1459 rows but variables found have 1460 rows".  

I realize now that this warning was due to other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a training set and test set to have the same number of observations. (In fact, often, the test set is much smaller than the training set.) Perhaps you've made a programming mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In real world it is almost never happen for the size of training set is equal to the size of testing set. Usually training set is much bigger than testing / production use.

Think about you want to build a handwriting digit recognition system, where your training set can be million samples of historical database. But testing / production can be only 5 digits zip code in one letter.

The reason you got the error is because you are using R incorrectly.

Here is an example that works well with different training (size 30) and testing set (size 2).

```
> d_train=mtcars[1:30,]

> d_test=mtcars[31:32,]

> fit=lm(mpg~wt,d_train)

> predict(fit,d_test)
Maserati Bora    Volvo 142E 
     18.35444      22.55856
```